# Can you add an old active account to a new device that has an active account already

Tags: clash-of-clans

My phone broke and my friend has Clash of Clans, I was wondering if I could switch out his account for mine but it says I have to delete his village.

Is it possible to switch back and forth without permanently deleting anyone's village?

Comment: no switch back and forth

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible in android. You have to add your google account in the accounts section in the settings. Once you do that ask your friend to disconnect his village from google+ and then reconnecting it (in the coc settings tab). Then the game will ask you which profile you want to log in to. Choose your profile. It will ask you to replace the current village. Just type CONFIRM. It won't result in any data loss or anything. Do the same for switching back to the previous profile (this time just disconnect n reconnect !). Cheers ! Happy clashing ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Neither the android or iOS approaches will successfully allow switching between villages if you did not save your village by linking to a Google+ or GameCenter ID.

@Deepan's answer is correct for Android. For iOS you do something slightly more complicated. You must log out of GameCenter, then log in as *YOUR* GameCenter ID.

A "GameCenter" ID is really an AppleID. But the "AppleID" used for iTunes purchases is independent from the GameCenter ID.

Here is the process of selecting a different village on (an older) iOS device. Find **Settings**, then **Game Center**

Next Sign Out (click the ID and confirm)

[image: GameCenter Sign Out]

Add the OTHER GameCenter ID and password and click Sign In.

When you go back to Clash of Clans (after some brief time) you should see:

[image: Are You Really Sure]